# Modify an .XML that is going to be install with msi installer. C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, installation

I have been trying out c#.net. 
I finished my solution and now I need an installer.
I'm using the visual studio installer. I need the user to input some information during the installation that I need to write into an XML. The XML is going to be copied into the installation folder. 
I cant find the way to access ANY code in order to work from there.

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: by _"visual studio installer"_ you mean InstallShield? do you look for others installers?

Comment: When creating a project, under "Other Project Types - Visual Studio Installer - Setup wizard"

Comment: there is [WiX installer](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/) which have a [special means](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/xmlfile.html) for editing XML file right on install step. I think you should try it. WiX is more powerfull and more easy to learn, then other (as far as I can tell).